# Disable multi click count on jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi i am trying to fix a bug on this plugin for wordpress I am using. The functions looks like this

```
function alter_ul_post_values(obj, post_id, ul_type) {
    jQuery(obj).find("span").html("..");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php  echo get_template_directory_uri() ."/includes/ajax_counter.php";?>",
        data: "post_id="+post_id+"&up_type="+ul_type,
        success: function(msg) {
            jQuery(obj).find("span").html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

and to call the function and count the click comes this line!

```
<span class='ul_dcont' onclick=\"alter_ul_post_values(this,'$post_id','wpt2_dislikes')\" >".$text."(<span>".  $dislike_nr ."</span>)</span>
```

Now if you click fast (multiclick) over the span it will count all clicks. I want to limit this to one click because the cookie is created after the click and doesn't allow any more clicks to be counted!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create global variable. It is not very cute way, but simple and effective.

```
var isProcessing = false;  // <- 1

function alter_ul_post_values(obj, post_id, ul_type) {
    if (isProcessing)      // <- 2
        return;            // <- 3

    isProcessing = true;   // <- 4
    jQuery(obj).find("span").html("..");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php  echo get_template_directory_uri() ."/includes/ajax_counter.php";?>",
        data: "post_id="+post_id+"&up_type="+ul_type,
        success: function(msg) {
            jQuery(obj).find("span").html(msg);
            isProcessing = false;  // <- 5
        }
    });
}
```

The other option is to change `span` to `input type="button"`, set `disabled` attribute on click and remove it on callback.

Comment: I used the easiest way and it did the trick well, i don't get it why you said its not very cute... but for me a sweet fix. Thank you a million :)

Comment: You're welcome.)  It isn't cute because the scope of variable is much more bigger than it should be. So, for example, if you attach another js-file with the same global variable (I mean the same name), you'll get unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

well, in ajax_counter.php
can you return response JSON object like

```
response.cookieSet = true/false;
response.msg = your stuff;
```

so you know cookie was set or not
then you can disabled a click on span